# How to include same code in several activities (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I have like 50 activities. Every activity opens random new activity like this:

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) {

Random generator = new Random();
int number = generator.nextInt(50) + 1;

Class activity = null; 

switch(number) {
case 1: activity = ActivityNumber1.class; break;
case 2: activity = ActivityNumber2.class; break;
...
case 50: activity = ActivityNumber50.class; break;}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Now, how could I write this code only once and include it on every activity?

I already have public int for keeping numeric value to be used between activities:

```
public class counter_global extends Application...
```

Comment: 50 activities? can you just reuse one of them instead of creating new ones?

Comment: I guess it could be more dynamic but every activity has different layout and content.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate it in a class so it can be reused as required:

```
class NewActivity
{
    static void openRandom()
    {
        // Insert your code here.
    }
}
```

And then in your activities:

```
NewActivity.openRandom();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a global abstract activity class "MainActivity" and make each of your activity inherit that class. Therefore, any subactivity will heritate your code, and it will be available everywhere.

Example :

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void openNewActivity(View view) {

    Random generator = new Random();
        int number = generator.nextInt(50) + 1;

        Class activity = null; 

        switch(number) {
        case 1: activity = ActivityNumber1.class; break;
        case 2: activity = ActivityNumber2.class; break;
        ...
        case 50: activity = ActivityNumber50.class; break;}

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And your subclasses activity

```
public class OwnActivity1 extends MainActivity {


}
```

And in your OwnActivity1, the method "openNewActivity" will be available, and you will be able to call it where you need. Main advantage of this method is that will allow you to make changes to ALL your activities at once later if you need it. For example, you can make changes on MainActivity to add a "parameter" button on top right side, or set a background color, or contextMenu, or actionBar, anything.

Answer (score 0):

1-Create class like this:

```
public class Util  
{
  public static Class getRandomActivityClass(){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int number = generator.nextInt(50) + 1;
    Class activity = null; 
    switch(number) {
      case 1: activity = ActivityNumber1.class; break;
      case 2: activity = ActivityNumber2.class; break;
      ...
      case 50: activity = ActivityNumber50.class; break;
   }
   return activity;    
  }
}
```

And use it On each Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Util.getRandomActivityClass());
startActivity(intent);
```

2-You can create base Activity Class and put Method On base and inherit activities from base class:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   public void runRandomActivityClass(){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int number = generator.nextInt(50) + 1;
    Class activity = null; 
    switch(number) {
      case 1: activity = ActivityNumber1.class; break;
      case 2: activity = ActivityNumber2.class; break;
      ...
      case 50: activity = ActivityNumber50.class; break;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity);
    startActivity(intent); 
  }

}
```